# Does anyone have any benchmaking data for Rstudio Server?

Tags: performance, r, rstudio

I need to set up a Linux server that will serve over 200 concurrent users, accessing an R studio server.

I will be creating J Meter scenarios to test this, but before I went through all that I would just be wondering if anyone else had encountered that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it took was a bit of RTFMING to find 
http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/latest/load-balancing.html

Answer is there.